# Sorting a zipped list in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Here is my code if you want to run it

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from treeinterpreter import treeinterpreter as ti
import operator


X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000,
                           n_features=6,
                           n_informative=3,
                           n_classes=2,
                           random_state=0,
                           shuffle=False)

# Creating a dataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Feature 1':X[:,0],
                                  'Feature 2':X[:,1],
                                  'Feature 3':X[:,2],
                                  'Feature 4':X[:,3],
                                  'Feature 5':X[:,4],
                                  'Feature 6':X[:,5],
                                  'Class':y})


y_train = df['Class']
X_train = df.drop('Class',axis = 1)

rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50,
                               random_state=0)

rf.fit(X_train, y_train)


importances = rf.feature_importances_
importances = X_train.columns

instances = X_train.iloc[[60]]


prediction, biases, contributions = ti.predict(rf, instances)
```

I have tried to sort the list in 2 ways, firstly using the itemgetter

```
for i in range(len(instances)):
    for c, feature in sorted(zip(contributions[i], importances), key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
        print (feature, np.round(c, 5))
```

Secondly, using the `key= lambda`

```
for i in range(len(instances)):
    for c, feature in sorted(zip(contributions[i], importances), key=lambda x: x[0].any()):
        print (feature, np.round(c, 5))
```

But running both solutions yielded the same output which was

```
Feature 1 [ 0.16033 -0.16033]
Feature 2 [-0.02422  0.02422]
Feature 3 [-0.15412  0.15412]
Feature 4 [ 0.17162 -0.17162]
Feature 5 [ 0.02897 -0.02897]
Feature 6 [ 0.01889 -0.01889]
```

I would like to sort the list using the first column of the above output, any ideas what I am doing wrong?

### Update 2 : Just clarifying the question

Sort them in feature order, rather than values inside the bracket of the feature

### Update 3 : How the output should look like if you arange with the first column

```
Feature 4 [ 0.17162 -0.17162]
Feature 1 [ 0.16033 -0.16033]
Feature 5 [ 0.02897 -0.02897]
Feature 6 [ 0.01889 -0.01889]
Feature 2 [-0.02422  0.02422]
Feature 3 [-0.15412  0.15412]
```

How the output should look like if you arange with the second column

```
Feature 3 [-0.15412  0.15412]
Feature 2 [-0.02422  0.02422]
Feature 6 [ 0.01889 -0.01889]
Feature 5 [ 0.02897 -0.02897]
Feature 1 [ 0.16033 -0.16033]
Feature 4 [ 0.17162 -0.17162]
```

### Update 4 Including an if condition in the sorting

print values with condition that they are greater than 0.01 and -0.01

Comment: Please, provide proper values for `contributions` and `instances`. Data structure is unclear, your code does not describe this

Comment: @Slam what do you mean sorry ? they are values of 'ti' as you can see when you scroll down in the code provided. You can run the whole code in your envirnment

Comment: @Victor shouldn't you sort by `key=lambda x: x[1]`?

Comment: @Greesha0 ofcourse not ! or atleast thats what I think. x[1] will try to sort the features rather than the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to cast your data in feasible format: `contributions.shape` is `(1, 6, 2)`. Having `contributions[0]` makes it easy to iterate with `zip`:

```
zip(importances, contributions[0])
```

will yield `name + [values]` pairs. Here's how to iterate over, sorting with lambda by chaining indexing:

```
for name, values in sorted(zip(importances, contributions[0]), key=lambda pair: pair[1][0]):
    print(name, values)
```

Lambda will take `name + values` pair, take `values` with `[1]`, and than first column of values with `[0]`.

Filtering is another task. Simplest way to read/debug code after is to just check values inside `for` loop:

```
for name, values in sorted(zip(importances, contributions[0]), key=lambda pair: pair[1][0]):
    if -0.01 < values[0] > 0.01: 
        print(name, values)
```

if `a < b > c` is cryptic, you can switch it to `not a < b < c`, or (in your case) `abs(b) > a`

Comment: just a small question, how to print the values such that it includes values greater than 0.01 and -0.01, rather than all values ? Thank you in advance. I will update the question to include this part

Comment: Added sample for filtering

Comment: you're a star !